# Ошибка в методе класса "TypeError: say() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, методы

Я недавно начал изучать Python 3. Начал экспериментировать с ООП. Создал простенький класс и запихнул туда метод. При вызове метода получаю ошибку.

Код:

```
class people:       
    name = ""
    age = ""
    def say(text):
        print("Said: " + text)

a = people()
a.name = input("What is your name? ") #Тут ввожу "Vlad"
a.age = input("What is your age? ") #Тут ввожу "19"
text = input("What do you want to say? ")  #Тут ввожу "Hello!"

print("Output")         #Вывод 

print(a.name)
print(a.age)
a.say(text)
```

Текст ошибки:

> TypeError: say() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Замените `def say(text):` на `def say(self, text):`

Comment: Раз начали изучать, почитайте, что передается в методы класса в качестве аргументов, и что такое `self`.

Comment: Что такое self в Python? https://toster.ru/q/254814

Answer (score 2):

Исправил ошибку и добавил вам функцию инициализации класса.

```
class people:       
    name = ""
    age = ""
    def say(self, text):
        print("Said: " + text)

a = people()
a.name = input("What is your name? ") #Тут ввожу "Vlad"
a.age = input("What is your age? ") #Тут ввожу "19"
text = input("What do you want to say? ")  #Тут ввожу "Hello!"

print("Output")         #Вывод 

print(a.name)
print(a.age)
a.say(text)
```

Но я бы немного изменил бы ваш код и сделал чуть рациональнее:

```
class people:       
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def say(text):
        print("Said: " + text)

name = input("What is your name? ") #Тут ввожу "Vlad"
age = input("What is your age? ") #Тут ввожу "19"

a = people(name, age)

text = input("What do you want to say? ")  #Тут ввожу "Hello!"

print("Output")         #Вывод 

print(a.name)
print(a.age)
a.say(text)
```

p.s. функция `__init__` (что значит initialization - инициализация) нужна для того, чтобы инициализировать класс. Вкратце: чтобы можно было сразу значения пихать в скобочки. Например: `a = myClass(firstThing, secondThing)`. Также всегда в функциях класса первым аргументом должно стоять `self`.